# Sometimes the click doesn't register in nightwatch.js

Tags: nightwatch.js

How do you handle the case where you asked nightwatch/selenium to click an element, but it doesn't click it so another element that you check is not visible. How do you handle the case where clicks do not work?

Comment: why doesn't it click it? it doesn't find it or is it dynamic and it changes the identifier? that should not be a case, if the test is correctly written. is there any error? could you put some code example that generates you this behavior?

Comment: plus, i see you asked this question before, should be closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096113/clicks-do-not-work-in-nightwatch-js